# How can I pass variable in xpath from the script?

Tags: java, selenium

```
WebElement selectRadioButton;

public void selectContractType(String txt)
    {
        selectRadioButton.sendKeys(txt);
        selectRadioButton.click();
    }
```

Tried like below,

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//*[@class='example-radio-button mat-radio-button mat-accent'][@value='"+txt+"']")
```

But getting error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wjzE.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please give your error-message as text! (So the search function works much better ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parametrize the `WebElement` which was denoted by `@FindBy` annotation. `@FindBy` annotation purpose is to initialize the elements while initializing the class as part of `PageFactory`. You need to do something like below,

Call this below into your method.

```
WebElement element = createWebElement("//*[@class='example-radio-button mat-radio-button mat-accent'][@value="+txt+"]");
```

Keep the below reusable method in Utility.

```
public static WebElement createWebElement(String elementText) {
    WebElement element = null;
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(elementText)));
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementText));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
    }
    return element;
}
```

Keep

```
WebElement element = createWebElement("//*[@class='example-radio-button mat-radio-button mat-accent'][@value="+txt+"]");
```

inside `selectContractType()` method and assign some value to `String txt;`

Comment: None of the above three solutions are working, getting error unable to locate element but the path is correct, the value "txt" is not getting passed to the variable

Comment: Can you show me.. how you tried?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/7UuTGkn9

Comment: Keep `WebElement element = createWebElement("//*[@class='example-radio-button mat-radio-button mat-accent'][@value="+txt+"]");` inside `selectContractType()` method and you haven't assigned any value to `String txt`.

Comment: Got resolved, thanks

Comment: Great catch within the comments (+1), you should update your answer with this text as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@class='example-radio-button mat-radio-button mat-accent'][@value="+txt+"]")
```

This should work if you want to pass txt string to @value.

Answer (score 0):

Well for such cases, I would suggest you to make use of `Format Specifier`.

For example:

```
String txt = "someValue";
String radioButtonLocator = String.format("//*[@class='example-radio-button mat-radio-button mat-accent' and @value='%s']", txt);
WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(radioButtonLocator));
```

Is this what you are looking for?